# Why soap based web service is not called when using backbone in android?

Tags: cordova, backbone.js

Could you please tell me why a soap based web service is not called when using backbone in an android app? The same code work fine when I run it in blackberry.

I know backbone support rest based web service. but I have added externally js to call soap based web service.

Comment: You’ll have to share a lot more of your code than this. Consider making a jsfiddle, it sounds complex.

Comment: _this.webservicesCall("HNH"); // here i am calling web service

Comment: webservicesCall : function(stationCode) {
   alert(" Web sevice call.......");
   var _this = this;
 this.$el.find('.arrival').addClass('loading_region');
   var pl = new SOAPClientParameters();               var parameter1 = stationCode;
   pl.add("parameter1", parameter1);
   SOAPClient.invoke(App.settings.server, "getArrivalStationDashboard", pl, true, _this.GetArrivalStationDashboard_callBack);
  }

Comment: GetArrivalStationDashboard_callBack : function(r) {
   console.log(" Web sevice response.......");
   alert(" Web sevice response.......");
   console.log(r);}

Comment: i am not getting "r"....

Comment: i am using this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12816/JavaScript-SOAP-Client

Comment: i am facing one more problem when i check on emulator with constant value and call webservice , it response will come but when same .apk file i insert in device response will not come..

Comment: EDIT your question and add some code, otherwise it's almost impossible to help.

Comment: Did you whitelist the url in config.xml?